# Horror short movie where an AI implant comes to think of itself as its owner, then is extracted and subjected to sense deprivation

Tags: story-identification

I'm currently searching for the name of a series (or a short movie perhaps?) that I have seen some time ago.

I remember the video shows a woman living her daily life in a smart home. Some time after she's undergoing some kind of surgery. They extract some kind of device which stores an AI that was placed inside that woman's head.  The AI believes it is the person it just got extracted from. From that moment on the AI lives in some kind of white vast room and has to control the smart home for her former self.

After she refuses, the salesman for this smart home control system just lets her sit inside this white empty room for a long time. Soon her mind is broken and she does as she has been told.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like *[Black Mirror: White Christmas](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3973198/)* episode.  One of the stories is

> Then Matt explains that he really worked with a chip called Cookie, capable to make a digital copy of the user. Then he forced the copy to serve the real user through torture manipulating time to break any resistance from the copy.

The description from [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SmartHouse) is even more on point:

> The Christmas Special of *Black Mirror* ("*Black Mirror: White Christmas*") features one where you create a mental copy of yourself to control your own house. So if you like to wake up to a certain song, demand your toast is done a certain way and are all-around fussy, then who better than yourself to make everything perfect? The catch, however, is that said mental copy is in every way like you and so isn't content to be your personal servant; the way to make them "compliant" is sensory deprivation to the extent where they will beg for even the most mundane of tasks to keep them entertained. You're basically torturing yourself to get a slightly less stressful life.